# Leer nodos de XML en mayusculas y minusculas

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, visual-studio-2013

Soy nuevo en esto y espero haber formulado mi pregunta bien. Estoy haciendo una aplicación usando asp.net con C# en VS2013, este desarrollo lee los XML de los proveedores de mi trabajo, ya tengo hecho el código que lee el archivo y parte de mi código que lo hace es el siguiente:

```
XmlNodeList xmlNodoComprobante = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("cfdi:Comprobante");
sFolio = xmlNodoComprobante[0].Attributes["FOLIO"].Value;
```

En este ejemplo le asigno a mi variable **sFolio** el valor que contenga la etiqueta **FOLIO** y hasta ahí va todo super bien. Actualmente me estoy enfrentando a que los proveedores me envían sus XML's y, al cargarlos, mi código truena porque en ellos la etiqueta *FOLIO* **no existe**, revisando su XML esa etiqueta la tienen como *FOLIO*, *folio*, *fOLIO* o infinidad de combinaciones que tendría que validar y nunca acabaría pues, como les comentaba, leo todo el xml.

Navegando por internet encontré esto:

```
string value = "aBc";
XmlNode xmlnode = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("/some/path/add[translate(@key, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = '{0}']", value.ToLower()));
```

y lo trate de implementar a mi código pero no funcionó, seguramente algo hice mal jeje...

```
XmlNode xmlnode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format(fileUploaded + "[translate(name(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = '{0}']", value.ToLower()));
```

(*fileUploaded* es la ruta de mi archivo)

¿Es correcto usar eso?, y si lo es, ¿me podrían ayudar a orientarme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar Linq para convertir los atributos en una lista iterable y aplicar los métodos de extensión `Where, select y FirstOrDefault`.

> Recuerda agregar el espacio de nombre: `System.Linq;`

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
string sFolio = xmlNodoComprobante[0].Attributes.Cast<XmlAttribute>()
       .Where(attr => attr.Name.ToUpper() == "FOLIO")
       .Select(c => c.Value)
       .FirstOrDefault();
```

---

Si vas a obtener el valor de otros atributos con ese mismo inconveniente entonces te sugiero que te crees un método de extensión para que reutilices el código.

Para el método de extensión debes crearte una clase, en el ejemplo lo llamare `XmlAttributeExtensions`.

```
public static class XmlAttributeExtensions
{
    public static string GetValue(this XmlAttributeCollection source, string name)
    {
        return source.Cast<XmlAttribute>()
            .Where(attr => attr.Name.ToUpper() == name)
            .Select(c => c.Value)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Y cuando proceses tu xml para la obtención de los valores de los atributos:

```
string sFolio = xmlNodoComprobante[0].Attributes.GetValue("FOLIO");
```

---

> [Cast](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=netframework-4.8): Convierte los elementos de un IEnumerable al tipo especificado.
>
> [Where](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8): Filtra una secuencia de valores en función de un predicado.
>
> [Select](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8): Proyecta cada elemento de una secuencia a una nueva.
>
> [FirstOrDefault](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.8): Devuelve el primer elemento de una secuencia o un valor predeterminado si no se encuentra ningún elemento.

Comment: jaja funciona de maravilla!!!

Answer (score 0):

Para facturación electrónica CFDI versión 3.3 SAT, México tiene un estándar con la descripción de nodos y elementos donde se define el nombre de los atributos combinando mayúsculas y minúsculas de la forma en que se describen ahí se debería de realizar la construcción y lectura del XML ya que al validarlo contra sus respectivos XSD podria causar problemas ya que no encuentra los atributos con los nombres correctos.

Tu idea y las que comparten funcionan porque normalizas o prevees varios casos solamente te comparto esta información para que la tomes en cuenta.
Saludos

Comment: Esto debería ser un comentario, considera revisar [answer], saludos.